# How can I deploy 'private' gems that my apps can access but no one else can get?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, heroku, rubygems

I have several apps which I want to share some common code. I'd like to gem the code and share/version it across the apps that way, although I don't want to publish it to a public gem server.

What are some options?

Comment: One option someone else pointed me to is to simply point Bundler at a git repository (see http://gembundler.com/git.html ). I'd need to ensure this can be done with a private git repo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems promising:

https://github.com/cwninja/geminabox/

Although I haven't used it myself, so I can't vouch for it. However, it was recommended in a thread I recently read on the official Rubygems Q&A site, where it was mentioned that the built-in rubygems hosting is not a recommended solution, and Geminabox was offered as a good alternative.

Note that it doesn't feature any authentication or security (except through obscurity, obviously), so depending on how sensitive those gems are you may want to add something in yourself (or even just whitelist by IP address).

Comment: Thanks - I've seen others recommend this as well.

Comment: Geminabox actually does support HTTP Basic auth, which you can of course configure in your web server of choice.

Comment: Regarding basic auth, I've put up a quick wiki page on a simple solution: https://github.com/cwninja/geminabox/wiki/Http-Basic-Auth

Comment: Geminabox completely rocks. That's what I've used for private gem servers. Setup is trivially easy.

Answer (score 10):

[GemFury](http://gemfury.com/) is what you're after, I think.

Comment: That looks very interesting, although I think I'd normally just run my own geminabox server.

Comment: It is worth considering GemFury if you're creating a lot a gems.  Geminabox has performance issues when things get large and you need to reindex.

Answer (score 8):

The way to do this is by unpacking your gem into the vendor/gems directory. You then tell Bundler where to find it using your Gemfile as normal.

First unpack the gem into vendor/gems. I'm assuming you have the gem downloaded and sitting in an open directory in front of you.

```
gem unpack your_gem.gem --target /path_to_rails_app/vendor/gems/.
```

Now update your Gemfile with a line like this:

```
gem 'your_gem', :path => "#{File.expand_path(__FILE__)}/../vendor/gems/your_gem"
```

Finally, use Bundler to install it and update your Gemfile.lock

```
bundle install
```

You now have a local copy of the gem installed into your Rails app.

You can now share the gem between your apps any way you like, by maintaining a symlink, a Git submodule, or a subtree.

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion for this is to use bundler, a private git repo and a git+ssh dependency.  The only problem will be that you'll need to find a way to manage the ssh keys as currently I don't believe bundler supports caching ssh keys.  You might be able to use the https://username:password@myrepo.... style syntax, but I haven't tried it.

Don't forget you always have the option of using `bundle package` to packaging your gems for deployment.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This looks like the best option if I can figure a way to handle accessing the private repository in a secure way. Not sure I want to embed a username/password in the Gemfile.

Comment: I should test if I can do this with sshkeys. Thanks -

Comment: If the server has access it should "just work", but if you're deploying to something like heroku I don't know how you'd manage your keys.  In that case I'd just package everything.

Comment: Doing `bundle package` and then copying my private gem into `vendor/cache` works for us on Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

github offers a number of private repositories for a small fee as well.

Comment: Can I deploy from there as a gem?

Comment: Well, many gems are stored there which we use daily (such as devise, etc.) so it must be possible, though, I have not tested it personally.

Comment: Thanks - Sorry, but I meant to ask 'deploy from a private repository as a gem'. Thnks!

Comment: You can deploy a private repository using Bundler:
a) Check in a .gemspec file at the root of your repository (see Yehuda Katz's articles [on developing using Bundler and gemspecs](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/) and [on writing gemspecs](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/04/02/using-gemspecs-as-intended/)).
b) [Set up a deploy key](http://help.github.com/deploy-keys/) for the gem's repo.
c) Add the private gem to your Gemfile using a git source pointed at the private git clone URL, e.g.

    gem "yourgem", :git => git@github.com:yourname/yourgem.git